# python cgi script won't write into xml file using lxml etree write method

Tags: python, xml, cgi, lxml

I am new to writing cgi scripts. I wrote a simple cgi script that is supposed to, based on the query string, either write a new record into xml file, or read and write it. When i try to read it, it works just fine, but it just won't write into xml file. My code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
from lxml import etree

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
option = form.getvalue("option", "(no data)")

print("Content-Type: application/xml")
print("")

#xmldom = etree.parse('../lab7/zadanie_ajax/opcje.xml')
xmldom = etree.parse('/home/stud2018/8mikolajczyk/public_html/lab7/zadanie_ajax/opcje.xml')

if (option == "add"):
    child = etree.Element("record") 
    title_text = form.getvalue("title", "(no data)")
    author_text = form.getvalue("author", "(no data)")
    title = etree.SubElement(child, "title")
    title.text = title_text
    author = etree.SubElement(child, "author")
    author.text = author_text

    xmlroot = xmldom.getroot()
    xmlroot.append(child)
    xmldom.write('/home/stud2018/8mikolajczyk/public_html/lab7/zadanie_ajax/opcje.xml')


if (option == "get"):
    print(etree.tostring(xmldom, pretty_print=True, encoding="unicode"))
```

I try to run the script the following way:

```
/cgi-bin/zad6ajax.py?option=add&title=q&author=w
```

After running it like that, I receive the following error:

-->

```
<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> --> -->
</font> </font> </font> </script> </object> </blockquote> </pre>
</table> </table> </table> </table> </table> </font> </font> </font><pre>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stud2018/8mikolajczyk/public_html/cgi-bin/zad6ajax.py", line 28, in &lt;module&gt;
    xmldom.write('opcje.xml')
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 2057, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.write
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 746, in lxml.etree._tofilelike
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 813, in lxml.etree._create_output_buffer
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 803, in lxml.etree._create_output_buffer
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
</pre>
```

Comment: here it would be xmldom.write(...) right? well, that doesn't work either. And when I try to run the script, the only response I get is XML parser error, but that is to be expected, since I don't print anything except the content-type when adding.

Comment: when i load the page, but as i said, it is irrelevant, because i do not expect for anything to happen when the page loads, just for the record to be inserted.

Comment: Well, I think that is not the problem, because even when I add a print("<database></database>") the XML parser error disappears, and yet the script does not save into the file.

Comment: So you're getting the parser error when you're trying to load the response from the above CGI script. So how are you testing this CGI script so we can show you how to see the actual error from the CGI script?

Comment: Doing a curl get request on your URL should show you the actual raw response from the CGI script.

Comment: OK, I wrote a simple html + js website to use the get request on the URL (i used xmlhttpresponse) - however, i get status 200 and no error, but no response (i try to send back the xml file) - it indicates that after the .write function, the script crashes.

Comment: Use curl to test and add `import cgitb; cgitb.enable()` to the start of your CGI.

Comment: Oh just noticed. When `option == "add"`, you're not printing anything so your test that tries to load the response as an XML file will fail. Why did you expect that you'll get an XML response? I should really get off SO when drinking.

Comment: okay, i added import cgitb and i got an error, added it in the post

Comment: thank you so much! i actually had to set chmod to 777 over 755 (i know, a reallllly dumb mistake), sorry for wasting so much of your time over something so stupid, I was sure I had it set before to 777

Comment: My fault for drinking and posting. Should have caught on earlier.

Comment: well, i can only say have a nice one, thanks once again!